# MySQL Select Formatting Data Type Issue

Tags: php, mysql, currency

I am trying to format a column of Decimals into a currency format for display on a web page -

```
$query = "SELECT id, year, CONCAT('$', FORMAT(price_avg_sold, 2)), CONCAT('$', FORMAT(price_sqft, 0)), pct_list_sold, adom, sold_nu, sold_chg, year_1, year_2, year_3, year_4, year_5, year_6, year_7, year_8, year_9, year_10
FROM c33062";  
$records_per_page=11;
$newquery = $crud->paging($query,$records_per_page);
$crud->dataview($newquery);
?>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="7" align="center">
  <div class="pagination-wrap">
          <?php $crud->paginglink($query,$records_per_page); ?>
       </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

When I change:  price_avg_sold,  in my SELECT statement to: `CONCAT('$', FORMAT(price_avg_sold, 2))`, that column of cells go blank and all others display, so there is no error returned.

I've also tried adding single quotes and same result, blank cells in the column even though there is still data in the cells in phpMyAdmin - `FORMAT('price_avg_sold', 2))`

Comment: please provide also database info of your columns

Comment: I would recommend not to use MySQL in this case to format the data. Just do it in your PHP using number_format.

Comment: As @toooni said, you can easily format the column using simple and easy PHP

Comment: I have the same `DECIMAL(10,0)` field and here is my result http://i.imgur.com/PEZrPjj.jpg?1 Please show us your table datatype

Comment: price_avg_sold column in MySQL is type decimal(13,0) and yes, in my research I'm thinking it IS better to format it PHP rather than in MySQL.